# How to read PDF on iPhone in narrower columns?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, files.app

How can I read the text of a PDF on my iPhone redrawn to fit narrower columns? So that the words on screen can be bigger and I won't need to scroll sideways to read a line.

The best I've found so far is, if I'm lucky and the PDF is friendly, I can Select All and copy->paste from the PDF into Notes. This is not the prettiest. Is there another way to read PDFs with bigger text, without just zooming in (which necessitates sideways scrolling).

Answer (score 2):

PDFs are designed to describe a fixed page layout, with items in set positions. They are not capable of 'live reflowing' the text, or wrapping it to the window.

That having been said, some desktop apps do offer re-flowing the text in a PDF, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader. (The ability may depend on the data in the document being configured in particular ways.)

You'll have to investigate third-party PDF readers on the app store, and see if any offer this feature.

As you say, otherwise your only option is to copy the text to some app where the text can be reflowed and laid out anew. But obviously there are issues with things like headers, page numbers, text items in other flows, and images.

Comment: The best way is to see if the author does have the pdf in a more user friendly format that you as the reader can control - typically HTML (or ePub)